# How can I view all of the variables that refer to an object?

Tags: python, variables, reference

In my understanding of Python, when I assign

```
A = 1
```

the variable `A` is a reference to an object with value `1` that could also be referred to by other variables.

How can I view/print/return all of the variables that refer to this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get a [dictionary of all variables currently in scope and their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041639/get-a-dict-of-all-variables-currently-in-scope-and-their-values).

```
d = dict(globals(), **locals())
```

Then create a list of all references in the dictionary where the value matches the object you are interested in:

```
[ref for ref in d if d[ref] is obj]
```

e.g:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = A
C = B
d = dict(globals(), **locals())
print [ref for ref in d if d[ref] is C]
```

output:

```
['A', 'C', 'B']
```