# How can I get the value of a variable named after another one in groovy?

Tags: variables, groovy

I have a variable that contains the name of another variable which I want to retrieve the value, e.g.:

```
def variable = "finalVariableValue"
def variableName = "variable"
```

How can I get variable.value as I only know variableName?

I've seen the a Binding could be used but I have a lot of variable that I need to put on this Binding object in order to make it works. Is the only way?

NB: this behaviour is really similar to the ant property extension mechanism.

Thanks,
Michele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By prefixing it with `def` you are not registering it in an object you can inspect, like a map; one could argue it is registered in the AST, but that is a rocky road.

My 0.03 are working with a map, with a binding, or with dynamic properties. Drop the `def` part and choose one of the solutions:

#### Map

Simply declare the `variable` as a key in a map:

```
def map = [:]
map.variable = "finalVariableValue"
def variableName = "variable"

assert map[variableName] == "finalVariableValue"
```

#### Binding (with script)

Use the script built-in binding. Note this only works with scripts:

```
variable = "finalVariableValue"
variableName = "variable"

assert binding[variableName] == "finalVariableValue"
```

#### Dynamic properties

Use some dynamic properties mechanism, like an `Expando` (also, you could use `getProperty` with `setProperty` and others):

```
class Container extends Expando {
    def declare() {
        variable = "finalVariableValue"
        variableName = "variable"
    }
}

c = new Container()
c.declare()

assert c[c.variableName] == "finalVariableValue"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking there was a more "groovy" way, but map should works.

Comment: AFAIK groovy lacks any access to a collection of the vars. I guess you wanted something like python's [`locals()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1041906/563890)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *script*'s scope, simply dropping the `Type` definition:

```
variable = 'value'
name = 'variable'

assert 'variable' == this.name
assert 'value' == this[this.name]
```

or using [`@Field`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html) annotation:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def variable = 'value'
@Field def name = 'variable'

assert 'variable' == this.name
assert 'value' == this[this.name]
```